# What will Detect Magic detect on a weapon touched by a Forge Cleric with Blessing of the Forge?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, cleric

When Blessing of the Forge is used on an object it becomes magical. What school of magic would this be? If a PC/NPC were to use Detect Magic, what would they learn? Would they know it would only contain the magic for 24 hours?

Use case:
I'm making a Forge Cleric with the Charlatan background. I plan to touch an item, make it magical, sell it off to someone (or trading it for a horse, etc), then skip town. The magic will wear off in 24 hours, so the common-folk wouldn't be the wiser until I'm gone. If a wizard used Detect Magic/did an arcana check, would the ruse still work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *Detect Magic* probably won't reveal the ruse

In 5th Edition, only spells are typically associated with specific schools of magic. Magic items and class features that are not spells are typically *not* associated with a specific school of magic. However, they were in some previous editions, so it is not uncommon for the DM to house-rule an appropriate school of magic for each item or feature (often based on the school of magic of that item or a similar one in a previous edition). Even if the DM does so, a standard +1 magic weapon enchantment and your Blessing of the Forge feature would both most likely be ruled as transmutation magic, which means that *Detect Magic* would not be able to tell the difference.

### ...But other factors might foil you

The *Identify* spell, also a first level spell, will almost certainly reveal your ruse. (I say *almost* certainly because it's ambiguous whether it would reveal the temporary nature of the forge blessing, or if it would just report that the weapon is *currently* a +1 magic weapon.) However, beyond that, you may need to put some effort into making the weapon look the part in order to make the ruse convincing. From the [DMG chapter on treasure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#MagicItemResilience):

> #### Magic Item Resilience
>
> Most magic items are objects of extraordinary artisanship, assembled from the finest materials with meticulous attention to detail. Thanks to this combination of careful crafting and magical reinforcement, a magic item is at least as durable as a regular item of its kind. Most magic items, other than potions and scrolls, have resistance to all damage. Artifacts are practically indestructible, requiring extreme measures to destroy.

While it is certainly possible to enchant a basic, ordinary-looking longsword, that's probably not what your gullible mark is expecting to see when you tell them you're selling them a magic weapon. You might need to either obtain a suitably ornate mundane weapon to complete the ruse (which will cut into your profit), or else come up with a plausible story as to why this particular definitely-not-fake enchanted weapon looks so basic.

Lastly, bad news travels fast. If you pull this trick a few times, expect rumors of a fraudulent magic weapon huckster to start preceding you. This will of course make your ruse much more difficult to pull off.

Answer (score 7):

The text states:

> At 1st level, you gain the ability to imbue magic into a weapon or
>   armor. At the end of a long rest, touch one nonmagical object that is
>   a suit of armor or a simple or martial weapon. Until the end of your
>   next long rest, the object becomes a magic item, granting a +1 bonus
>   to AC if it’s armor or a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls if it’s a
>   weapon.

So, yes, the object is magical in nature, because it is a 'magic item'. However, it is not a *+1 weapon*, it is a magic weapon with +1 to rolls. The closest this is similar to is the 2nd level spell *magic weapon*. On that note, that would suggest this ability resembles the school of magic of *transmutation*, not *enchantment*, except Detect Magic's description says

> If you sense magic in this way, you can use your action to see a faint aura around any visible creature or object in the area that bears magic, and you learn its school of magic, if any.

And this has no school of magic, because it's a class feature. In addition, Detect Magic doesn't detect the duration of the magic on the item, merely that it is, in fact, magical.

As a DM, I might rule that a character proficient in Arcana checks might be able to tell that it isn't a *+1 weapon*, (remember, *magic weapon* exists as a spell, so this scam is probably common), certainly, say, an Artificer, but anyone without experience in magical items wouldn't be able to. On that note, since it's a Cleric ability, someone with Religion proficiency would also be able to tell the object's true nature.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94844/discussion-on-answer-by-halfthawed-what-will-detect-magic-detect-on-a-weapon-tou).